# Scheduled events in web development

Tags: php, web-development-server

I am working on a web application that requires php code to run at a specific date/time.

Some hypothetical examples would be sending a user an email at 09:00 on their birthday or modifying a database entry (mySQL) at a predetermined date and time.

What would be the conventional way to implement this kind of scheduling feature?
I've seen cron-jobs been used for similar requirements but would this be feasible for a large amount of scheduled tasks?

Comment: I would create a script, handling the birthday thingy for all users and run that script as a cronjob. 1 script for 1 cron job.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense now that I think about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the size of your project, but usually we don't have one script do all the cron jobs, because things need to happen at different times. Some emails might send at 9pm, some database cleanup might happen at midnight, and sessions might expire every few minutes. The best thing to do is set up separate cron jobs for each thing. There are a couple exceptions for this:

1. Some tasks need to run very frequently, like every 30 seconds. For that we set up a cron task which checks "ps" to see whether its own process is already running, and have it just wait 30 seconds and loop.
2. Some tasks make more sense to run when a queue is full. For that we trigger the task when a certain user-based script executes the 100th or 200th or 300th time. For example when a user pings 100 times without doing anything else, we log them out without using a cron task, but there is a separate cron task which checks if they've been inactive for 10 minutes.